# Strange behaviour of integer overflow

Tags: c++, c++14, integer-overflow

I created the following code for finding the answer to the coin problem. This involves finding minimum number of coins of given k denominations (where each such coins are in infinite supply) to form a target sum n. In particular I have investigated the case where `k=5`, denominations = `{2,3,4,5,6}` and target sum `n=100`.

**Code**:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int coins[5] = {2,3,4,5,6};
int values[101];
int n=100;
int k=5;
int INF = INT_MAX;

int main()
{
    for (int x=1;x<=n;x++)
    {
        values[x] = INF;
        for (int j=1;j<=k;j++)
        {
            if (x-coins[j-1]>=0)
            {
                values[x] = min(values[x],values[x-coins[j-1]]+1);
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<values[100];

    return 0;
}
```

The output to this code that I received is `-2147483632`. Clearly some kind of overflow must be occurring so I decided to output `INF+1`. And I got `INT_MIN` as the answer. But I had also remembered that often while outputting some numbers beyond the int range there was no such problem.

I decided to output `1e11` and to my surprise the answer was still `1e11`. Why is this happening, please help.

Comment: Signed integer overflow invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: signed integer overflow is undefined, In practice it may still appear to work, thats why your experiment didnt help to resolve the issue. UB that appears to work is still UB

Comment: Maybe not your problem, but you should set `values[0] = 0;`

Comment: `1e11` has the type `double` and is a value that is perfectly representable by `double`.

Comment: @Damien, thanks but still getting the same answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I had written 1e11 to represent 100000000000 which is what I actually printed.

Comment: @Damien -- since it's defined at file scope, all of the elements in `values` are set to 0. Explicitly setting `values[0]` to 0 doesn't change anything.

Comment: @PeteBecker Effectively, I did not pay attention that all variables are global here. Being of bad faith a little bit, I can say that I always try to avoid such situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 values[x] = min(values[x],values[x-coins[j-1]]+1);
```

For example, for `x=3` and `coins[0]=2`, you add `values[1] + 1`.

However,  `values[1] = INT_MAX`. Then, you get an undefined behavior when performing this calculation.

You can solve the issue with `INF = INT_MAX - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

If your program performs arithmetic on signed integers that produces result that is outside the range of representable values - i.e. if such operation overflows - such as in the case of `INT_MAX + 1` then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I decided to output 1e11 and to my surprise the answer was still 1e11.

1e11 is a floating point literal. Floating point types have different range of representable values from int, and different requirements regarding overflow.